# How to make the <br/> in jquery ajax response add a new line in html

Tags: jquery, ajax, servlets

I am using jquery ajax to send and receive data from a servlet. For example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('button').click(function(){
                $.post('/test/hello',{no:'5'},function (response){
                    $('#div').text(response);

                });
            });
        });
```

And this is my code in hello.java servlet

```
 String no = request.getParameter("no");
        int n = Integer.parseInt(no);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            out.println("hello<br/>"); 
        }
```

However when I get the response from the servlet, hello followed by break tag is printed 5 times on screen in one continuous line i.e break tag is not interpreted as html but as text.

How do I get Jquery to interpret the break tag as a new line so that I get the output like this?

hello 
 hello 
 hello 
 hello 
 hello

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are sending HTML in the response use [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead of [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

```
$('#div').html(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `.append()`:

```
 $('#div').empty().append(response);
```

because `.text()` parses the html as a string and puts as a string.

You can use html too:

```
$('#div').html(response);
```